# Django - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm learning Django from djangoproject https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial04/.

-Currently I'm on Part-4 of this tutorial.

However, it is showing an error while fetching a record from database table `Poll` as :

```
def detail(request, poll_id):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    context =  {'poll' : poll}
    return render(request,'polls/detail.html', context)
```

It shows an error :

```
ValueError at /polls/2/
```

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Please help with the issue........as i am completely a newbie to this framework.
I'm using MySql as my DBMS.
This is how my urls.py looks like :

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

    from polls import views

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^(?P)\d+/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
        url(r'^(?P)\d+/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
        url(r'^(?P)\d+/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote')
    )
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please add your urls.py

Comment: try casting `poll_id` to `int`

Comment: @am1ty9d9v: Yes i hv tried that....but no luck

Comment: Then this means you are not getting the `poll_id`. Try to add a `print poll_id'` statement just after the `def` line to see what `poll_id`'s got

Comment: @am1ty9d9v : I'm getting **poll_id** = 20 in place of 2 and 10 in place of 1....

Answer (score 4):

Change your url patterns to capture the pk element per the documentation. Django urls can capture named groups, hence `poll_id`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

Comment: :: Thanks ,but it is showing an error **TypeError at /polls/20/

detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'**...when i replaced `poll_id` named group with `pk`

Answer (score 2):

You need to check URL in your template.
you need to pass the integer id to URL `{{user.id}}` because url need to have integer value in template.

```
Ex.  url:-  /polls/{{user.id}}/
```

Hope this will work for others.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too.

My case it I had a typo in my form template. Double check the poll detail template (“polls/detail.html”) for typos.

Answer (score -1):

simply replace

```
poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
```

with

```
poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=int(poll_id))
```